# CentOS PHP upgraded, now downloads all pages

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php56

I had to upgrade PHP to 5.6 to get access to a new function for locales and translation. I removed the old PHP and added the new PHP from the `Remi` repo as specified [here](https://www.mojowill.com/geek/howto-install-php-5-4-5-5-or-5-6-on-centos-6-and-centos-7/).

I restarted Apache and now going to any page on the server prompts for download. I searched extensively, and PHP 5 is loaded as a module:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule !prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>
```

The `configtest` does also return `php5_module (shared)`. I've also tried many handlers and `AddType`s, this is one I have in currently in `httpd.conf`:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

So why doesn't Apache serve the PHP files?

EDIT:

I ran the following commands:

```
yum remove php-common
```

Then installed php5.6 exactly the way the link described.

Then updated the `httpd.conf` with the second code block with the `AddType` and `SetHandler`.

This was all I did.

EDIT:

```
php-common-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-dba-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-zip-1.13.1-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64
php-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-cli-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
wbm-php-pear-1.5-1.noarch
php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64
php-pdo-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-gd-5.6.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

is the result of `rpm -qa '*php*'`

Comment: The only thing I see which may be applicable is `[Sun Nov 22 03:41:06.763977 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7002] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.16 SVN/1.7.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
` So it says PHP 5.4.16 is configured, but I removed it... How do I configure PHP 5.6 because I thought I had already done that with the previous steps?

Comment: We don't know. You haven't described what you actually did.

Comment: All I did was remove the old PHP packages, and installed the new PHP 5.6 the way described in the link I provided at the beginning.

Comment: Just saying that you followed a guide doesn't work. Unless you can  show us _exactly_ what you did, nobody can be sure.

Comment: The output of  "rpm -qa '\*php\*' would help. Notice: you don't have to change httpd.conf. Never. "php" package put the needed configuration in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

Comment: @RemiCollet updated the question with more details

Comment: Are you certain you restarted Apache? That log entry is from six days ago!

Comment: Oh wait. The log file goes chronologically downward. Here's the most recent log `[Sat Nov 28 16:04:31.088545 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14852] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.6.16 SVN/1.7.14 configured -- resuming normal operations`. This looks like the only applicable statement.

Comment: wbm-php-pear looks strange to me... seems a virtualmin server... not a CentOS one.

Comment: Yes, virtualmin is installed, but its running on CentOS. Does virtualmin change anything?

Comment: I have no idea how much altered is the distro when installing virtualmin. According to Apache signature "PHP/5.6.16" is installed, so should work.

Comment: Yeah, I mean Virtualmin also states that PHP 5.6.16 is installed.